# pdf.js upload second file but show first content, how to show second content

Tags: javascript, pdf, canvas, pdf.js

I want show second upload file content in canvas,but it always show first one.

This is my html:

```
<input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile" value="upload">
<div>
<button id="prev">prev</button>
<button id="next">next</button>
<span>Page: <span id="page_num"></span> / <span id="page_count"></span></span>
</div>
<canvas id="the-canvas"></canvas>
```

canvas first img will be right, but others are wrong.

This is my js:

```
var pdfjsLib = window['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'];      
pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = 'https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js';

var pdfDoc = null,
pageNum = 1,
pageRendering = false,
pageNumPending = null,
scale = 1.5,
canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas'),
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


$("#myfile").on("change", function (e) {
var file = e.target.files[0];
var fileReader = new FileReader();

fileReader.onload = function () {

var pdfData = new Uint8Array(this.result);
// Using DocumentInitParameters object to load binary data.
var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument({data: pdfData});



function renderPage(num) {
pageRendering = true;
// Using promise to fetch the page
pdfDoc.getPage(num).then(function(page) {
var viewport = page.getViewport({scale: scale});
canvas.height = viewport.height;
canvas.width = viewport.width;

// Render PDF page into canvas context
var renderContext = {
canvasContext: ctx,
viewport: viewport
};
var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);

// Wait for rendering to finish
renderTask.promise.then(function() {
pageRendering = false;
if (pageNumPending !== null) {
// New page rendering is pending
renderPage(pageNumPending);
pageNumPending = null;
}
});
});


document.getElementById('page_num').textContent = num;
}


function queueRenderPage(num) {
if (pageRendering) {
pageNumPending = num;
} else {
renderPage(num);
}
}


function onPrevPage() {
if (pageNum <= 1) {
return;
}
pageNum--;
queueRenderPage(pageNum);
}
document.getElementById('prev').addEventListener('click', onPrevPage);


function onNextPage() {
if (pageNum >= pdfDoc.numPages) {
return;
}
pageNum++;
queueRenderPage(pageNum);
}
document.getElementById('next').addEventListener('click', onNextPage);


pdfjsLib.getDocument({data: pdfData}).promise.then(function(pdfDoc_) {
pdfDoc = pdfDoc_;
document.getElementById('page_count').textContent = pdfDoc.numPages;

// Initial/first page rendering
renderPage(pageNum);
});


};


fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);



});
```

pdf.js upload second file but show first content, how to show second content,thanks a lot
pdf.js upload second file but show first content, how to show second content,thanks a lot
pdf.js upload second file but show first content, how to show second content,thanks a lot